# Entity Frame Work Data Base first Initialise

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, design-patterns

I am a student and beginner with Entity Frame Work Code First / DataBase First and MVC.
I am using the second one (DataBase First).
I created my database, generated the model from Database.
My question is that:

How can I initialize some default data (in the database)?
In *code First pattern*, there is a method called `seed`:

```
protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
```

Is there an equivalent of this method using the *DataBase First pattern*?

Answer (score 1):

In database first approach the database already exists so your application doesn't have any data initialization. Data initialization is used only when the application code creates the database (code-first) which is not your case.

You must simply put some data to your database either by using native SQL script or some database client tool like SQL Server Management studio or Visual Studio with Server Explorer.

Comment: Thank for answer
The goal is simply to be able to update my database at startup if there's been such creation of a new table (by changing my context), without having to update the model (. edmx) my self.
A bit like the seed method does with the Class Initilizer (DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges)

Comment: In such case don't use EDMX and use code first. Simply database first says that your application doesn't have control over your database and because of that it cannot seed it. Also seed will change only data in the database not table themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i did with Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1 which you can use via Extension Manager. After creating edmx model & installing tool right click on project and click "reverse engineer code first" and you'll get code first model of you database. Then you your db already have data you need to create new db from codefirst and export data from your previous db. If you are interesting in it i can show it by steps.